# Is there any way to clear the implicit text on a QTextEdit widget in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

```
LogInPage::LogInPage(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::LogInPage)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    
    connect(ui->username, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this,
            &LogInPage::clearTextEdit);
}

void LogInPage::clearTextEdit()
{
    ui->username->clear();
}
```

I have tried this code, but with no success. Do you guys have any other suggestions? I have also tried this:

`void on_username_clicked()` in the private slots of the header with the same clear function, but it did not work.

Comment: First of all, that code doesn't make a lot of sense: what would be the point of clearing a text field whenever it's changed? Not only it would prevent typing anything into it, but it would also cause recursion (and I'm surprised that you don't get any issue from it). Then, what do you mean by "clear the implicit text"? Finally, since that widget is clearly used as a single line text field, you should use QLineEdit, not QTextEdit. Please take your time to [edit] your question and explain more clearly what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I am new to QT and this is why I am not really familiar with it. I changed the QTextEdit with QLineEdit as you said. Hopefully I will be able to explain what I want. The thing I want to achieve is that when the Log in window shows up, the user sees where he needs to insert his username and password and when he clicks on the username QLineEdit for example, that username text I first inserted there as a guide to dissapear and let the user insert his credentials. Is it clear enough?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [`QLineEdit::placeholderText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop).

Comment: @ValentinAxinescu As said by G.M. above and shown in the duplicated answer I linked above, QLineEdit natively provides the `placeholderText` property (which is also available in Designer). Since you're new to Qt I strongly suggest you to take your time to always carefully study the documentation of each class you use (including the inherited ones) so that you better know their purpose, how they work and what features they provide. Looking at **all properties** each widget provides in the Designer's Property Editor is a good start.

Comment: Thank you all guys. This is exactly what I wanted, the placeholderText. I will try and study the documentation, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @ValentinAxinescu Good. Please accept the duplicate proposal, there should be a button/link on top of your question.